# simple way in PHP to split path string into breadth-first array

Tags: php, arrays

Using PHP 5.2, I'm trying to parse an arbitrary number of path/directory strings into an array, such that they can be processed breadth-first. This is to allow me to script a sparse checkout from a Subversion repository, telescoping the indicated paths. All the paths on the same level have to be specified in the same `svn update --depth empty` statement.

I get the desired output, but I wonder if there's a cleaner way to do this. (And, yes, I know there are changes needed for efficiency.)

**EDIT** I modified the original post to handle cases of multiple children in the same parent. My revised code is

```
$main = array(
    'a/b/c1/',
    'a/b/c2/d/e1',
    'a/b/c2/d/e2',
    'A/B/',
    'alpha/beta/gamma/delta/epsilon'
);

$splits = array();
$max = 0;
for ($i=0; $i<count($main); $i++) {
    $splits[$i] = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, trim($main[$i], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
    if (count($splits[$i]) > $max) {
        $max = count($splits[$i]);
    }
}

for ($i=0; $i<$max; $i++) {
    $levels[$i] = array();

    for ($path=0; $path<count($splits); $path++) {
        if (array_key_exists($i, $splits[$path])) {
            $levels[$i][] = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, array_slice($splits[$path], 0, $i+1));
        }
    }
    $levels[$i] = array_unique($levels[$i]);
    sort($levels[$i]);  // just to reset indices
}
```

This changes my output structure to the following, which both provides unique directories at each level and retains sibling nodes.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => A
            [1] => a
            [2] => alpha
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => A/B
            [1] => a/b
            [2] => alpha/beta
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => a/b/c1
            [1] => a/b/c2
            [2] => alpha/beta/gamma
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => a/b/c2/d
            [1] => alpha/beta/gamma/delta
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => a/b/c2/d/e1
            [1] => a/b/c2/d/e2
            [2] => alpha/beta/gamma/delta/epsilon
        )

)
```

In my code, I then iterate over the final `$levels` array. Unfortunately, this still requires two iterations: one for `depth empty` and one for `depth infinity`, but I'm sure that could be worked out.

```
$count = count($levels);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    echo '<p>', 'svn update --set-depth empty ', implode(' ', $levels[$i]), "</p>\n";
}

$count = count($main);
for ($i=0; $i<$count; $i++) {
    echo '<p>', 'svn update --set-depth infinity ', $main[$i], "</p>\n";
}
```

Comment: This isnt a direct answer but i wonder if whatever your processing is you might just be better off using [`RecursiveDirectoryIterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) to implement it :-)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think that will help. I added more information. With a sparse checkout, I won't have any directories to iterate.

Comment: A clean solution would have involved a PHP function doing that, but there is no such thing in the standard library (eg. there is nothing like array_union_recursive). Either gain some kind of abstraction by coding it yourself (but then you'll have to think about weird edge cases), either keep your code like this. The current code is really easy to read!

Comment: ALso, do you realize how complicated it would be to handle the case with multiple children? You'd need to duplicate the parent twice, which is difficult. I have a nice hack wich is shorter than your code, but would never handle the multiple children case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$levels=array();
$depth=0;
$i=0;
foreach ($main as $m) {
  $m=explode('/',$m);
  while (sizeof($m)<$depth) $m[]=null;
  $d=0;
  foreach ($m as $mm) {
    if ($d>$depth) {
      if (!$mm) break;
      $depth=$d;
      $levels[$d]=array();
      for ($j=0;$j<=$i;$j++) $levels[$d][$j]=null;
    }
    $levels[$d][$i]=$mm;
    $d++;
  }
  $i++;
}
```

looks like a good alternative with only one traversion of the array. In short you don't use one pass to decide on the depth, but if you encounter a deeper entry, you just fill the relevant places in the array retroactively with nulls.

$depth has the depth-1 after the loop.

**Edit:**

This does yet handle a case of multiple children in the same parent, but I am unsure if it does so the way you want

Comment: Thanks, Eugen. Your answer did simplify the original post. Feel free to have a go at the revised version. :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my implementation (it got easier with your latest request):

```
$levels = array();

for ($i=0; $i<count($main); $i++) {
        $splits = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, trim($main[$i], DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR));
        $current = array();
        /* Load every subpath in an array*/
        for($j=0; $j<count($splits); $j++) {
                $current[$j . "hack"] = implode("/", array_slice($splits, 0, $j+1));
        }
        $levels = array_merge_recursive($levels, $current);
}

/* Removes duplicates and resets indices */
array_walk($levels, function(&$l, $i) { $l = array_unique($l); sort($l); });
```

What makes this implementation simple is that I handle each path separately. I only have one loop, and join the results with `array_merge_recursive`. For example, with "a/b" and "a/c", my code :

1. creates `array(0 => array("a"), 1 => array("a/b"))` and `array(0 => array("a"), 1 => array("a/c"))`
2. joins them with `array_merge_recursive` which gives `array(0 => array("a", "a"), 1 => array("a/b", "a/c"))`
3. removes unique values with `array_unique`
4. resets the indices with `sort`

Note: I need to use `$j + "hack"`, otherwise `array_merge_recursive` won't merge the values as expected (try it for yourself).